# Scrapping with parallelelized wget/curl command

Tags: scraping

I created a script which tries all possible combinations of a hash(number) of a URL which represents a link to some social media file (video or audio) like [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={hash}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%7Bhash%7D) or [https://ok.ru/video/{number}](https://ok.ru/video/%7Bnumber%7D) or etc. The script runs thousands of wget commands in parallel to figure out whether the URL is valid (represents an existing media) and writes it into a log if true.

Purpose: Create a huge hashmap (hash -> title) which contains all valid links and use it offline for a full search. Why? Because I convinced that the search mechanism of almost all social networks is not full: something is skipped by complicated algorithms (depending on location etc), someones do output only limited number of occurrences. Also it is never exact search (only whole word, no special chars) etc etc. I want a stupid and guaranteed sub-string search like "grep" which searches all volume of data and never misses. Also my approach opens possibility to search by exact duration.

I convinced on practice that if the script runs in 100+ parallel instances and on several PCs at the same time it becomes very efficient and according to my measurements I need only several months to pass all combinations of URLs for a certain big social network if I have 20-25+ PCs. But I have not such resources at home.

Questions:

1. Where I can find such web services which provide me sufficient number of PCs with different IP for each PC for my experiment? Is AWS a good choice for this?
2. Is it legally dangerous to do what I want? I mean is there a threat of something more serious than just an IP ban? I do know every URL which I test is public, so there should be no problem theoretically, but I would prefer to feel safe if possible.

Comment: This site is for business environments. We don't give recommendations and we especially don't give legal advice.

Comment: *"I need only several months to pass all combinations of URL's"* immediately gives a small feasibility concern  because by the time you've exhausted all hash values a portion of content will already have been deleted, invalidating the hash location and probably even more new content  will have been added.

Comment: There are about 10^19 possible combinations of youtube hash alone. To go through them all in 3 months (10^6 seconds) you need to do 10^13 checks per second. How much bandwidth do you need for that if you get at least one packet per check?

Comment: YouTube is the hardest one that should be considered separately, because its hashes are not ascending by date. But for VK, OK, Spaces (and other primitive websites, for sure) they are ascending, so it is pretty feasible. The recently appeared items won't be counted, yes. But since the number of new items (let's say for last 6 months) is dramatically smaller than the whole size it can be easily beaten by running of the script once again from time to time with "from N=..." parameter for achieving of the latest uploaded stuff.

Comment: For instance, I tried also browser VMs, a nice one was www.onworks.net and I tested it well, but it is a browser VM which closes the session after 5 min of inactivity. If I find a similar with no limit I can open let's say 20+ tabs in a browser and run it there completely parallel on remote side.
I found also many other browser VMs. but they have isolated network inside a container which prevents accessing real internet.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerating sequential IDs in order to access some hidden objects is called [Insecure direct object reference (IDOR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insecure_direct_object_reference). If the objects aren't intended to be public, accessing them could be considered illegal in some jurisdictions (IANAL).

Major social platforms are well aware of IDOR and apply appropriate measures - randomized IDs, proper auth checks etc. They also don't like scrapers and apply request rate limits. I would expect that an attempt to scrape with a request rate of 100 rps would end in a few minutes with 429. I have the impression that scrappers spend most of their effort finding and managing proxies to bypass rate limit restrictions. Bypassing restrictions would definitely violate ToS and could also be considered illegal in some jurisdictions (IANAL).

From the technical point of view, the idea grossly underestimates the amount of resources needed. There are billions of sites, Google index contains hundreds of billions of documents. Even if we simplify the task to just existing YouTube videos, there are 20 billion of them. `curl` to a YouTube video to get a title returns about 700-800 Kbytes, which amounts to 14 PBytes for all videos. It would require 14 GBits/per second for 3 months. `time curl` shows about 0.1-0.2s of user+sys time, which means we can do about 5 requests per CPU core per second (without any scheduling and postprocessing overhead). To process 20 billion requests in 3 months it would require 400 CPU cores. To store 20 billion entries with a hash and video title (say 100 bytes) we need about 2 TB of storage without any indices. Simple `grep` in a 2 TB file would take about 10 minutes from SSD and 2 minutes if it is in the memory. To get a reasonable search response time <5 seconds we need to spread the search over at least 25 instances with a total of 2 TB RAM which would result in 80 GB RAM per instance. To get a total of 400 CPU cores we need at least 16 vCPU per instance. The cheapest instance that fits the requirements is `r6g.4xlarge` which costs $588 per month on demand. The total cost of 25 instances would be $14700 per month.

Comment: Thanks for your professional estimations, Alexey. I agree the task is quite difficult in a maximal scope.
What about "hidden objects" and IDOR topic. I understand I have to be careful. The problem is however that the formulation is not 100% clear. I am not going to access hidden objects, but iterate through all objects and note those ones which are public. If I reference a hidden object during this iterative process it must lead to an "access denied" error. If it turns out to be accessible due to a bug it is not my fault, because my intention is to take all public ones, right?

Comment: Just for comparison. I am in a big library which is full of bookshelves. The catalog says there is no book that I want, but I don't trust and start looking just every single book in the library and write down its title and shelve/position number. I don't approach the locked shelves, only open ones. After I finally leave the library with a huge list of records about the seen books, am I a thief or a cheater?

Comment: The questions about legality are off-topic here. You'll be able to find better answers on https://law.stackexchange.com/